# Array of objects coming into server as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to send a property of the current state as (an array of objects) to my server. When I tried to log it in my server its returning as an array of [object Object]. JSON.stringify only adds "" around each object.

```js
//sending my current players property to here
getFantasyPros: function(players) {
    return axios.get("/api/scraper/" + players);
  },

//end point
router.get("/:players", (req, res) => {
    const playerArr = JSON.stringify(req.params);
    console.log(playerArr);
}
```

Comment: Probably your objects in the array are empty?
Be sure that the JSON.stringify has no bug :D

So the only problem I see here is that you're not passing to the server what you think you're passing, or at least not in the way the server wants.

I'd say to you to show more code

Comment: What is in the `players` variable ?

Comment: I'm passing this.state.players into the players variable. When I log it on the front end I return the array of 8 objects. Logging on the server though it returns an array of 8 [object Object] objects though.

Comment: 0: {_id: "----", name: "Doug Baldwin" ,__v: 0}
1: {_id: "----", name: "Matt Breida", __v: 0}
2: {_id: "---", name: "Zach Ertz", __v: 0}
3: {_id: "----", name: "Sony Michel", __v: 0}
4: {_id: "----", name: "Lamar Miller", __v: 0}
5: {_id: "----", name: "Carson Wentz",  __v: 0}
6: {_id: "----", name: "Deandre Hopkins",  __v: 0}
7: {_id: "-----", name: "Alvin Kamara", __v: 0}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: You cannot pass an object as paremeter to a url. You will have to `JSON.stringify` the players and then `encodeURIComponent` before adding them to the URL, and then on the server `JSON.parse` it,  although it looks like bad architecture passing whole objects as url params. Using `.post` insteaf of `.get` might be a better approach if you have to send all that data.

Comment: Thanks, changing to a post worked. I don't know why I didn't try that before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something via your response (res). Add to the end of your endpoint.

```
return res.json({
  playerArr,
  msg: 'It worked'
})
```